# Reverse animation on page transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have a few pages on my website and i made a header animation (pulldown). So, i need to reverse my animation (pullUp) when the other one page is clicked. Is there any option to do that ? Or is there any option to make the second animation (pullup) active when the other page is selleced

```
header{
  background-color:black;
  height:80px;
  text-align:center;
animation-name: pullDown;
    -webkit-animation-name: pullDown;   

    animation-duration: 2s; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;

    animation-timing-function: ease-out;    
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;    

    transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;       
}

.pullUp{
    animation-name: pullUp;
    -webkit-animation-name: pullUp; 

    animation-duration: 1.1s;   
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.1s;

    animation-timing-function: ease-out;    
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;    

    transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;         
}

@keyframes pullUp {
    0% {
        transform: scaleY(0.1);
    }
    40% {
        transform: scaleY(1.02);
    }
    60% {
        transform: scaleY(0.98);
    }
    80% {
        transform: scaleY(1.01);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scaleY(0.98);
    }               
    80% {
        transform: scaleY(1.01);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scaleY(1);
    }                           
}

@-webkit-keyframes pullUp {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.1);
    }
    40% {
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.02);
    }
    60% {
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    }
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.01);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(0.98);
    }               
    80% {
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.01);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
    }       
}
```

Comment: Attach the animation to a class, and do a class toggle with js.

Comment: Note, both `@keyframes` appear to reference `pullUp` animation. Can you include `html` at Question , create a stacksnippets to demonstrate ?

Comment: here is the example for header animation http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPrObw

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options I can recommend:

1. Use CSS's `:active` selector to bind to the hash of the "pulldown" item:

```

## second-page:active ~ .drawer {

```
animation: "pullUp" 1s linear;
```

}
```

So that when the user clicks on the url to your second page (`#second-page`), the animation will trigger, thus hiding the drawer itself.

2. Use Javascript to toggle classes:

(jQuery)

`var $drawer = $(".drawer");
var $drawerToggle = $(".drawer-toggle").on("click", function() {
    $drawer.toggle("fast");
}`

3. Use an `input[type="checkbox"]` 'hack':

`.drawer-toggle:checked ~ .drawer {
    animation: "pullDown" 1s linear;
}
.drawer-toggle ~ .drawer {
    animation: "pullUp" 1s linear;
}`

Comment: But if i use for example css, how my html code should look ?

Comment: i copied js code, and it's still doesn't work, should i attach some plugin or just make js file and copy that code ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zrXrXM but as i told, when i click on `<a>` element, page transition is instantly. Is there any possible way to stop transition for a few seccond ?